# fql get valid photo

Tags: facebook-fql

I have written a fql to get photo from facebook.

```
fql = 'SELECT caption, owner, pid, src_big, created 
         FROM photo 
        WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid 
                        FROM album 
                       WHERE owner IN (111111) ) 
        LIMIT 1,10';
```

But I found sometimes the app cannot get the photo from the src_big column.

How to write a fql or any other methods to make sure the returned photo url (e.g.src_big) is accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Facebook API:

> The URL to the full-sized version of
>   the photo being queried. The image can
>   have a maximum width or height of
>   720px. This URL may be blank.

I think your issue is that you don't always get a src_big image. You should also query for the src_small image, as a fallback. Also, you can add a default image of your own, so that if neither image is available or acceptable, you can just use your default image.

For example:

```
    fql = 'SELECT caption, owner, pid, src_big, src_small, created 
         FROM photo 
        WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid 
                        FROM album 
                       WHERE owner IN (111111) ) 
        LIMIT 1,10';
```

And then in your code, check for something like....

```
//Where results = photo results array...

for(var i = 0; i<results.length; i++){
  if(results[i].src_big == null){
    if(results[i].src_small == null){
     //Use default image
    }
    else{
      //Use src_small
    }

  }
  else{
    //use src_big
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks spoonybard, in fact the src_big has value, just dont know why the image from that url cannot be accessed.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood the issue then. Is it a bad URL or something? Are you getting an error code or anything like that?

Comment: It is a bad URL, and I dont know why facebook store bad URL in the table "photo".  Therefore, I dont know whether there is any method to make sure those selected url are NOT bad url. Thx.

Comment: I've run into something similar before, and the only solution that we were able to come up with at the time was checking that the URL's didn't return an error code before trying to display them. The obvious downside to this though is that you have to make a whole bunch of HTTP requests to check those URL's.